# Как запретить PhpStorm менять мои пропуски строк (Enter'ы) в коде при «Reformat Code»?

Tags: phpstorm, ide, форматирование

Я расставил столько `Enter`, сколько мне нужно.
Сделал `Reformat Code` и все `Enter` изменились.
Как настроить `Reformat Code`, чтобы он не трогал `Enter`?

Comment: **File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Необходимый Вам Язык**. Там ищите раздел **Blank Lines**. Там можно выставить максимальное количество пустых строк между объявлениями и прочим

Comment: Там нет Blank Lines. Есть галочка Keep indents on empty lines. Я нажал, но это не помогло.
Вот скриншот:
https://ibb.co/nMZzKw

Comment: В таком случае могу предположить, что для этого расширения файла это не сделать никак) А зачем вам тогда вообще Reformat Code? Поправлять отступы?

Answer (score 1):

У SCSS форматтера минимум собственных настроек, но при форматировании используются настройки CSS - **Settings | Editor | Code Style | CSS**, в частности, **Other | Blank lines between blocks**. К сожалению, эта опция контролирует только количество пустых строк между блоками.
Если хочется больше возможностей контролировать форматирование, проголосуйте, пожалуйста, за [WEB-29588](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29588), [WEB-19525](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19525) и [WEB-13957](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13957)

Также могу посоветовать исключить фрагменты кода из форматирования с помощью комментариев - см. https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000689870/comments/115000579590